# Get part of the text with regular expression with c #

Tags: c#, regex

In the following text:

> Groups Targeted by I.R.S. Tested Rules on Politics (Author: NICHOLAS CONFESSORE)

I need to get the author's name using regular expression. How to get the expression in this case?

I try this

```
Regex.Match("Groups Targeted by I.R.S. Tested Rules on Politics (Author: NICHOLAS CONFESSORE)", @"(?<=Author:\s+)[^)]").Groups[0].Value;
```

The result is only the character "N"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried at the `gskinner`, here is the [link](http://regexr.com?350o5)

The result was: `(?<=Author:\s)[^)]+`

Answer (score 2):

You can match from `Author:` to a closing parenthesis:

```
(?<=Author:\s+)[^)]+
```

Note that this assumes that an author name itself will not contain a closing parenthesis. Whether that assumption is valid depends probably on your data set.

`(?<=foo)` is a positive lookbehind which will not consume any characters in the match but instead anchor the match to the point where `foo` precedes the rest of the regex. So in this case we would start matching right after `Author:`. `[^)]+` is a negated character class containing every character but the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Using the code 'var a = Regex.Match("Groups Targeted by I.R.S. Tested Rules on Politics (Author: NICHOLAS CONFESSORE)", @"(?<=Author:\s+)[^)]").Groups[0].Value;' The result is only the character "N"

Comment: Add a `+` at the end. You are actually only matching one character now. `(?<=Author:\s+)[^)]+`

Comment: Eep, sorry. I constantly make that mistake, I fear.